# pie chart is not showing in android

Tags: android, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to show pie chart . For this purpose I have the following code :

```
public class Piechart extends Activity
{

  GraphicalView mChartView = null;
  private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
  private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("Expenses");
  private static int[] COLORS = new int[]{    Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Color.DKGRAY, Color.BLACK};

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Cursor cursor; 
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    double[] values = new double[count];
    String[] categoryNames = new String[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {   
        cursor.moveToNext();  
        values[i] = cursor.getDouble(1);
        categoryNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    int i = 0;
    mSeries.add(categoryNames[i], values[i]);
    SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    i++;
    mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mChartView.setLayoutParams(params);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartsRelativeLayout);
    layout.addView(mChartView);
  }
```

But in the following code I have an error . The error is "The method setDisplayChartValues(boolean) is undefined for the type SimpleSeriesRenderer".

```
 renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

I am following the tutorial in this link . http://mukeshsoni.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/how-to-setup-achartengine-within-an-activity/

Can you please help me ?

Comment: try [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/03/piechart-using-achartengine.html) or [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/03/piechart-using-achartengine.html)

Comment: The activity is not run in your links code . Please detect error in this code . Thanks